# Dianoga SVGO Additional Tool Arguments Syntax

Tags: dianoga

I am using Dianoga for SVGs. I would like to disable removeViewBox. What is the syntax for adding additional arguments to SVGO? Here is what I have (that does not work):

```
<dianogaOptimizeSvg>
    <!-- Optimize the SVG with SVGO https://github.com/svg/svgo -->
    <processor type="Dianoga.Optimizers.Pipelines.DianogaSvg.SvgoOptimizer, Dianoga">
        <ExePath>/App_Data/Dianoga Tools/SVGO/svgop.exe</ExePath>
        <AdditionalToolArguments>-disable={removeViewBox}</AdditionalToolArguments>
    </processor>
</dianogaOptimizeSvg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for Dianoga, it appears that the Additional Tool Arguments parameter for SVGO are not wired up. I'll need to make my own version of Dianoga.Optimizers.Pipelines.DianogaSvg.SvgoOptimizer. Luckily it looks like I will be able to swap out my own implementation fairly easily.

Comment: I'll be happy to accept a pull request with this improvement.

Comment: Once I figure out how to make it work I will gladly submit one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SVGOP was built with a preset list of plugins. And it is not possible to change *svgop.exe* behavior in runtime.

What is possible is [to build your own executable](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-executable-from-almost-any-npm-package-three-tishchenko/) using [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg):

```
//install svgo
npm i svgo
//install pkg
npm install -g pkg
//make your own executable from svgo
//if you don't want to play with passing any parameters using Dianoga, 
//prior this step you can change plugins list of plugins configuration under \node_modules\svgo
npx pkg node_modules/svgo
```

Or you can try [Dianoga 6+ version](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/releases), where it should be possible to pass configuration to SVG optimizer.